# Grails get file from xhr

Tags: ajax, grails, file-upload

how grails get file from xhr?
my ajax

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()  
xhr.open("POST", "actionGrails", true)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.send(file);
```

when in my controller

```
def actionGrails() {
def f = request.getFile('file')
println f//get error
}
```

any solution for this? thanks

Comment: `xhr.send(file)` is not a valid approach.  see [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211145/upload-file-with-ajax-xmlhttprequest

Comment: hi brian, thx for you reply, but how can i access the file from formData with grails?, i have search but is always php example, i need grails example, thanks

Comment: you could try changing the accepted answer in the link, `formData.append("thefile", file);` to `formData.append("file", file);` to work with your action.  All this is speculation, though.  You should post the error you're getting, to get better answers.  possibly also the declaration of 'file' in your client-side code.

Comment: i just want to save the file to my folder using p.transferTo(new File('../LGN-cms/web-app/uploads/)) in grails, or can ajax transfer the file to my folder without grails command? because i dont need to save the file to my db, but to  my specific folder. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: use [Fine Uploader](http://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader). It has a [demo page](http://fineuploader.com/#demo).

The Grails plugin which packages the library is [here](http://grails.org/plugin/ajax-uploader) .

Comment: hi jinzhao, thx u reply, u reference it's to complex, u have any reference in grails? thanks

Comment: thanks for you answer, but i dont need plugin, i just want to know how grails get params.file from ajax/jquery command. thanks

Comment: Like other frameworks do, Grails got it from the form submitted from views. There should be some description in docs, depending on what lib/plugin you adopt.

Comment: yeah, but i use angular in frontend, and grails in backend, so i wonder to know how i pass params.file because i want to save the file in some folder, thanks anyway