# FormData sends files but $_FILE is empty

Tags: php, file, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, form-data

I have no idea why i keep getting an empty $_FILES global array when i print it out. Ive been looking it over but i can't see where i am going wrong. because of that i have shown all of the code.
if i use the button it reaches the server just fine and everything works out. but if i use the drag and drop then i get no files on the server? any idea why? when i print the array it is array(0).

I found one problem with the while loop which i now fixed still no files tho.
just incase people are wondering if the post action is correct. The url is rewritten using mod_rewrite. It displays the correct php pages so i am assuming the the pages is reached. would mod_rewrite affect the uploading of files. I don't think so...?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
            <title>Music Upload</title>
            <style>
                  #zone
                  {
                        height:300px;
                        width:500px;
                        border:1px solid black;
                  }
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
            <div id="zone">
            <legend>Drop a file here&hellip;</legend>
            <p>Or click button to <em>Browse</em>&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <form action="../receive/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>


            <script>
                  function dragover(event)
                  {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log("drag event");
                        return false;
                  };
                  function dragend(event)
                  {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log("drag end event");
                        return false;
                  };
                  function drop(event)
                  {
                        console.log("Files droped");
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var files=event.dataTransfer.files;
                        fileupload(files);

                  };

                  function isMp3(file)
                  {
                        console.log("Check if mp3 file");
                        mimeTypes=['audio/mpeg','audio/mp3','audio/x-mpeg-3'];
                        for(var i=0;i<mimeTypes.length;i++)
                        {
                              if(file.type==mimeTypes[i])
                              {
                                    return true;
                              };
                        };
                        return false;
                  };

                  function fileupload(files)
                  {
                        if(files.length>0)
                        {

                              var formData= new FormData();
                              var i=0;
                              while(i<files.length)
                              {
                                    var file= files.item(i);

                                    if(isMp3(file)){
                                          formData.append('file[]',files[i++]);
                                          console.log('valid mp3');
                                    }
                              }
                              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                              xhr.open('POST','/mymusic/receive',true);
                              xhr.onload=function()
                              {
                                    if(this.status==200)
                                    {
                                          console.log('data sent');
                                          console.log(this.responseText);

                                    }else
                                    {
                                          console.log('data failed');
                                    }
                              };
                              xhr.upload.onprogress=function(event)
                              {
                                    if(event.lengthComputable)
                                    {
                                          var complete=Math.round(event.loaded*100/event.total);
                                          console.log(complete+"%");
                                    }
                              };
                              xhr.send(formData);
                        }
                  };

                  var dropArea=document.getElementById("zone");
                  dropArea.addEventListener("dragover",dragover,false);
                  dropArea.addEventListener("dragend",dragend,false);
                  dropArea.addEventListener("drop",drop,false);
                  console.log('script loaded');
            </script>
      </body>
</html>
<?php exit();?>
```

Here is the server file. it doesn't really matter but just incase

```
<?php

echo "server reached\n";
  var_dump($_POST);
  var_dump($_FILES);
  exit();
?>
```

Comment: if you change the name to file_up instead of file[] ??

Comment: i don't see why that would affect it. I have file[] because it's an array of files that will be coming in and they have the same name. not the name of the files but the name value for the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload File With Ajax XmlHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211145/upload-file-with-ajax-xmlhttprequest) worded differently but the answer should be the same

Comment: nope not a duplicate he was sending the file and not the formdata object it self. I am sending the formdata

Comment: ps url are rewritten is the reason i don't have extensions on the file. I know that will come up so i answered

Comment: Just for testing....with just one file and see if the upload is working...if not then the problem maybe can be your Javascript code

Comment: i tested it with one file and it says that it's uploading in the progress in the console.log but when i get to the server it's empty

Comment: The problem is with the javascript as it works fine if they use the form. I cannot see where OP is setting the multipart/form-data in the JS but as I am no JS expert I will bow out

Comment: @Anigel you shouldn't sent the content type when using FormData as the browser must set that itself to include the boundary name.

Comment: Fair enough I just saw it was set in some previous answers, and know that in the case of normal forms, files will always be missing on the server without it.

Comment: Why is your form action set to `../receive/`? Is it called `index.php`?

Comment: url rewritten. it reaches the pages because it prints the array. it's just empty

Comment: @Lpc_dark have you tried/tested it without it being rewritten?

Comment: no but i really don't think that would matter because the file upload works when it's not the drag and drop and i use the button. If the rewritten was the problem wouldn't that fail as well?

Comment: @Lpc_dark I don't know if it would fail. Try it and see. It's part of "Troubleshooting" ;-)

Comment: sigh k but i really doubt it. ill give it a shot

Comment: blasphemy now it works. that's some serious bull. hmm maybe url rewritten can't work while uploading a file. doesn't really make any sense to me tho can anyone explain? why does the standard form work but the formdata doesn't?

Comment: @Lpc_dark So it works without the rewrite, yes? As for explaining it, I can't answer that.

Comment: ye it did makes no sense to me. if you want to post the answer i will give a nice checkmark i know you can't really explain why tho but it's okay.

Comment: @Lpc_dark Indeed, most bizarre. Answer posted. Glad it works for you though. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it without the `rewrite`, that is most probably the issue.