# Putting input file into FormData jquery to submit to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http-post

I know already got question for this problem but i still cant did it properly. Need some help.

I need to upload a file with additional data with it.

**my input.php:**

```
<input type="file"  id="foto_path" name="foto_path"  />
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="javascript:sendForm()" />
```

**I send that with javascript :**

```
function sendForm() {
    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#foto_path');
    var oMyForm = new FormData();
    var nip=123223374;//it will be generated by php, for temporary i just hardcode it
    oMyForm.append("foto_path", fileInput);
    oMyForm.append("nip",nip );
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "upload-file.php", true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
          //oOutput.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
          alert('success');
        } else {
          //oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>";
          alert('failed');
        }
      };
    oReq.send(oMyForm);
}
```

**and when I send that to upload-file.php:**

```
logapp("post -> ".print_r($_POST,true));//logapp is just function to log to file
logapp("files -> ".print_r($_FILES,true));
```

**I got this from log:**

```
09/07/2013 02:47:06 pm :: post -> Array
(
    [foto_path] => [object HTMLImageElement]
    [nip] => 123223374
)

09/07/2013 02:47:06 pm :: files -> Array
(

)
```

I got success alert but I need to get files for `foto_path` as `$_FILES` not `$_POST`. 
My Question is why input files detected as `$_POST["foto_path"]` not as `$_FILES["foto_path"]`. How to change that to `$_FILES["foto_path"]` so I can start work with the files uploaded?

Comment: Check this question [Upload File With Ajax XmlHttpRequest][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211145/upload-file-with-ajax-xmlhttprequest

Comment: i still got `[object HTMLImageElement]` in `$_POST` how to change that to files?

Comment: Note that `formData()` is not supported in IE <= 9. However, it seems to be no matter nowadays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

update : i solved this problem at last

```
var ft=$('#foto_path_upload')[0].files[0];
oMyForm.append("foto_path_upload", ft);
```

and this i got this from log :

```
09/07/2013 04:26:53 pm :: files -> Array
(
    [foto_path_upload] => Array
        (
           [name] => noimages.jpg
           [type] => image/jpeg
           [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php4E90.tmp
           [error] => 0
           [size] => 3642
         )

 )
```

Problem solved. thanx everyone

Comment: why we have used [0] to access file upload element - '$('#foto_path_upload')[0]'

Comment: Sorry i forgot why i using [0]. Maybe because i have many element with id "foto_path_upload" so it need to be spesific which one i want to access... just try without it..

Comment: @Arjit may be a late reply but he is using [0] to make it a dom object from jquery object
you can directly do var file = document.getElementById("foto_path_upload").files[0] ;)